# How do I connect and send ZPL instructions to a network printer?

Tags: c#, printing

I have been able to connect using TcpClient by the ip address and everything works.

I was told I need to change it to connect to the printer on the network by name, because the ip address will change. My question is, how would I go about doing this?

This is how I am doing it right now

```
string zplString = "zlp print instructions"
string printImage= "zlp instructions for png"

using (var client = new TcpClient())
 {
   client.Connect(ipAddress, 0);
   using (var writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream()))
   {
    //Write ZPL String to connection
    writer.Write(zplString);
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Write(printImage);
    writer.Flush();

return;
 }//Close streamwriter
 }//Close Connection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by getting the ip address dynamically with IPHostEntry  and using it in the TcpClient connection

```
  IPHostEntry IPHost = Dns.GetHostByName(printerName);
  string[] aliases = IPHost.Aliases;
```